# Efficient way to replace nodes in a networkx graph with follow-through edges

Tags: python, replace, networkx

I am trying to replace nodes in the graph with follow-through edges. This means that each predecessor of the replaced/removed node will be connected to each successor of the replaced/removed node.

For example, considering a path graph with 5 nodes such that edges `(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)`, I wish to replace nodes 1 and 3 with follow-through edges (`(0,2)` for node 1) and (`(2,4)` for node 3). The final graph should have the edges `(0, 2), (2, 4)`.

Comment: i doubt you will find any networkx magic much faster than the 'naive' way you described earlier (add edges from each predecessor to each successor and delete the node). though, `itertools.product` is your friend here. assuming these are only ever singles (would you ever e.g. remove both 1 and 2 and replace with 3? that's a different algorithm...)

Comment: That's what I figured. I am guessing that this is a specific use case not applicable to most users and hence might not be included.

In my use case, I determine all nodes that should not be replaced and the rest must be replaced with through edges. So it is possible that i need to remove 1 and 2 to get `(0,3), (3,4)`. Is that what you were asking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Networkx has no built-in functions/algorithms for it so you should do it manually. [Itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) module will help you to automatize the construction of edges to create:

```
import itertools as it
import networkx as nx


G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([
    (1,2),
    (2,3),
    (3,5),
    (4,5),
    (5,6),
    (5,7)
])

nodes_to_delete = [2, 5]
for node in nodes_to_delete:
    G.add_edges_from(
        it.product(
            G.predecessors(node),
            G.successors(node)
        )
    )
    G.remove_node(node)
```

So `G.edges` will return the needed edges (`1->2->3` moved to `1->3` and `3,4,6,7` are pairly connected):

> `OutEdgeView([(1, 3), (3, 6), (3, 7), (4, 6), (4, 7)])`

---

**P.S.** I doubt if the more efficient method in networkx exists. In `networkx` you should check each node's predecessors/successors so the O-complexity will be the same anyway.